# What value does JavaScript Date() provide?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to understand what the value of JavaScript's Date() function represents.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p> Current date time:</p>
<p id="d"></p>
<p> Number of Milliseconds since 1970/01/01: </p>
<p id="d1"></p> 
<p> Number of Days since 1970/01/01: </p>
<p id="dn"></p> 

<script>
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = d;
    document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML = d/1;
    document.getElementById("dn").innerHTML = d/(1000*60*60*24);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the output:

```
Current date time:
Thu Apr 18 2019 16:03:20 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Number of Milliseconds since 1970/01/01:
1555617800698
Number of Days since 1970/01/01:
18004.835656226853
```

My question is the last number I would assume is how may days it has been since 1970/01/01.  It's 4:03pm or 16:03 right now. 16/24 = 0.6667 or that the day is 2/3 done.  Yet the result above is .8356 suggesting it is 8:00pm (.8356x24-12).

What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing that the base time is midnight UTC, not your own timezone.

Comment: EDT is 4 hours behind UTC.

Comment: Thanks Barmar.  I should have figured that out - long day. Post this as an answer and I'll vote it solved. Cheers.